# Why does JMDict not have an entry for 作り込む?

Tags: discussion

JMDict has [219 entries](https://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/srchres.py?s1=1&y1=4&t1=%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80&src=1&search=Search&svc=jmdict) ending in `込む` (including 突っ込む and 落ち込む and 乗り込む), but none for **作り込む**.

"作り込む" has definitions in [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80), [Goo](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80/), and an [English](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A%E3%81%93%E3%82%80) translation on Weblio. It's a single morpheme in UniDic (動詞-一般 (general verb), 五段-マ行 (godan, "ma" column).) The string "作り込む" has ~470'000 hits on Google.

Is this just an incompleteness in JMDict, and should we try to create a [new entry](https://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/edform.py?svc=jmdict&c=1)? (If I can ask, what definitions would you suggest?)

Or might there be some reason why nobody's created this entry before? Perhaps something violating its [editorial policy](https://www.edrdg.org/wiki/index.php/Editorial_policy)?

Comment: If this question has an answer, I don't think it's one related to the Japanese Language itself. Perhaps better suited for the meta site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a guess, but this may have something to do with the fact that 作り込む is a relatively new compound verb.

[青空文庫全文検索](https://myokoym.net/aozorasearch/search?word=%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A%E8%BE%BC) (contains public-domain literary works mainly before 1960) has only a few examples for 作り込む, and most of them seem to have different meanings from today's 作り込む. On the other hand, [BCCWJ](https://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/) (corpus of modern written Japanese) has lots of examples of 作り込む as we use today.

Either way, 作り込む is a very common verb in modern Japanese, and definitely
it should be included in dictionaries. (My suggestion would be "to detail; to polish; to perfect; to bring to completion", but I may be wrong. For the sake of completeness, we should also include the other definition, "to make (inside something)", although we rarely use it in this sense today.)

By the way, [作り込み](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF) has been already listed on jisho.org. (I feel "detailing" or "polishing" may be better considering the modern usage of this word, but again, I may be wrong.)

Comment: I submitted the new entry, using your suggestions for the definition: https://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/entr.py?q=2846379&svc=jmdict&sid= I hope this is ok with you, let me know and I'll try to reword the definition. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @AhmedFasih My English is not good enough, and I'd love to have this checked by a native English speaker (If you are, nevermind).

Comment: gotcha, as a native English speaker, the English definitions sound perfect to me. Hopefully the JMDict editors can help ensure they're accurate and… *polished* :)

Comment: Jim Breen has accepted the submission. He changed the order of the definitions a bit and deleted one, and also added some cross-references and another kanji  (造り込む). Hooray! Thank you so much! https://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/entr.py?q=2846379&svc=jmdict&sid= (Also sorry for using English slang "gotcha" above instead of just saying "understood", I have a bad habit of using that word.)

Comment: Superb! You can now see the new entry in Jisho: https://jisho.org/search/%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80 and the other online and offline dictionaries should catch up soon!

Comment: Question about correct usage of BCCWJ: I went to the link you provided, clicked the "no registration" Shonagon link, which sent me to https://shonagon.ninjal.ac.jp/ where I click the red button at the bottom that says "...少納言を使う", click "OK", type in 作り込む in the box at the top (no quotes), leave all checkboxes checked. I only see two hits, from 2005 and 2001. Did I do this correctly?

Comment: @AhmedFasih It's an unparsed corpus, so try `作り込` and `作りこ` instead.